# WordPress: Hide Div If Empty

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I just finished converting my HTML to WordPress. You can see it [here](http://zulhilmizainudin.com/live/?paged=2).
I choosed one post per page display.

But, I noticed that I don't have 'Previous' link and div. I only have 'Next' link and div now.

If I add 'Previous' link and div, how do I hide it in my home page (a latest entry goes here)?
And, how do I hide 'Next' link and div at the last entry and only show 'Previous' link and div at this [last entry page](http://zulhilmizainudin.com/live/?paged=3)?

This topic is more to WordPress Pagination topic I guess. Hope that you guys can help me. I'm new in this WP development. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show me your pagination code? Do you use standart WP pagination or some plugin?

Comment: Do not add background(styles) for the ".pagination" element. Instead add styles for the ".pagination a" element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you use standart WP pagination:

```
global $paged;
$range = 4;
$showitems = ($range * 2)+1; 

if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   
if(1 != $pages) {
         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  // Show NEXT link if exists
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>"; // Show PREV link if exists
}
```